# Can not handle Windows pop-up (robotframework)

Tags: robotframework, autoit, sikuli

After I select print button then "Save PDF File As" pop-up will appear.
I want to press enter or press save button but I can not handle it.
However, I can handle the same pop-up in another page of system.

I use a lot solutions but not work. The pop-up did not change anything.

When I click "save" button by manual or press "Enter" by manual
log shown step passed.

**This below solotions is not work for me.**

1) [use SikuliLibrary]

SikuliLibrary.Press Special Key        ENTER

2) [use Sikuli]

```
Click              ${path_picture_save_button}
```

3) [use Autoit]

```
Control Focus  strTitle=Save PDF File As  strText=&Save    strControl=Button2
Control Click  strTitle=Save PDF File As  strText=&Save    strControl=Button2
```

4) [use resource function python"sendkeys"]

```
import SendKeys

def send_enter_key():
    """
    Sends ENTER key to application
    Works only in Windows
    """
    SendKeys.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBqXd.png)

Comment: I came across this before and we used Autoit and it worked. This was a while ago and don't remember the specifics, but it was a Windows only solution.

Comment: You 've tried Autoit and the Autoit Window Tool shows the information, but it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I used Autoit but doesn’t work. I have faced this issue only IE. Chrome is work. My work need to test only on IE.